# loadFile function does not download file when called on main thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am currently developing an iOS app that takes the streamable url of a music file from dropbox and plays it on the device. 
When the user clicks a song, it opens a view controller and there, i want to have the option to download the file. So i have an IBAction:

```
- (IBAction)availableOfflinePressed:(id)sender {
    NSString *trackPath = sharedApp.trackTitle;

    NSLog(@"Available offline pressed for %@", trackName);

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"Started downloading...");
        [self.restClient loadFile:trackPath intoPath:trackPath];
    });
}
```

Now, even though it throws the "started downloading..." in the app log, the file is actually never downloaded. I know that the dropbox sdk rest client does not execute functions when in the background, that's why i use the GCD on the main thread.

So, can you help me here? am i missing something?

thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Perhaps you should put it on its own thread with a run loop (the run loop is important). Also be sure you have the correct entitlements on your app. See, for example, [iOS Core API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/ios).

Comment: iOS programming & objective c beginner here :/ can you share some code please?

Comment: There's a sample app provided by Dropbox available at [iOS SDK](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/ios).

Comment: that doesn't help that much 'cause i don't know exactly what to look for..

Comment: Have you implemented the delegate methods `loadedFile` and `loadFileFailedWithError`? See https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/ios#downloading. If so, which is firing, and is there an error?

Comment: Yes, i've implemented them but none of those two methods are fired.

Comment: Also the loadedFile() function is fired and downloads the file as expected if i call it from the didSelectRowAtIndex() function, where the user selects the file to be played, so i am assuming there is something wrong with the background execution of this task. or not?

Comment: The code looks fine, though I'm not an iOS expert. (I would have thought there's no need for the `dispatch_async`, since I would have expected the `IBAction` to be invoked on the main thread.) Have you tried stepping through `loadFile` in the debugger? And maybe set a breakpoint on `requestDidLoadFile` to see if that's being hit?

Comment: can i step through the loadFile() with the debugger ? i don't think so because i only have the headers of the sdk..

Answer (score 0):

turned out it was a pretty silly answer!
the restClient was nil and not correctly set within the specific view controller, so it could not fire the dropbox delegate.

Actually, what was needed is to init the restClient as you might already do in your AppDelegate or anything and then set `self.restClient.delegate=self;` in the `viewDidLoad()` function of the specific view controller.

thanks everyone for your responses!
happy coding!